# Remove the status bar background in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Im trying to build a fullscreen app in Xamarin.Forms to target both Android, and iOS. I know how to hide the status bar in iOS from a previous app, but I am having difficulties doing so in Android. I have tried doing so by setting the application theme to

`@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen`

to no avail, as well as setting the UI flags using

```
this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
this.Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = StatusBarVisibility.Hidden;
```

which still leaves the different colored status bar minus all the info. But it throws off the design, and I can't seem to find any answers online anywhere.

Comment: Which API are you seeing this on? Setting the app style should do it... You have a screen clip to show what it looks like?

Comment: API is 24 ( i believe the most current) I can upload a screencap in the morning

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AppCompat then this is a known issue since Forms adds an underlay to the status bar which remains even when the system icons are hidden. Fortunately there should be an API added to the next Forms pre-release that should fix this: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=38019

In the meantime, you can try using reflection to set the underlay view's height to 0. After the call to `base.OnCreate()` do:

```
this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
this.Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = StatusBarVisibility.Hidden;

if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
{
    var statusBarHeightInfo = typeof(FormsAppCompatActivity).GetField("_statusBarHeight",  System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    statusBarHeightInfo.SetValue(this, 0);
}
```

Comment: I am unable to get the reference to `FormsAppCompatActivity` Is there a specific Assembly reference I need to use?

Comment: Add `using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android` to the class file or use `typeof(global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity)` instead.

Comment: What API does this target?

Comment: API 23 and using the latest Forms version (2.3.2). The target framework versions for Forms Android projects needs to be API 23 or higher.

The answer also assumes you are using [AppCompat](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/android/appcompat/). If not, then just setting the full screen flag should work. If you're still having trouble it would be best include a minimal reproduction project.

Answer (score -1):

In case you have not found the solution, here it is
I am not quite sure about the hiding status bar but if I remember it correctly adding `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);`to code behind was the solution for me.

If you want to change the color, you just need to add couple of lines.

1. Add `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/blue</item>` to your styles.xml file
2. And add `Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);`to your OnCreate method in MainActivity.cs